# pyspark java gateway issue while getting sparkcontext

Tags: pyspark, anaconda

here's the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate();
```

when getting sparkcontext,i got this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\jv219\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 93, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

i;m new to pyspark,please take a look at this, thanks a lot.

Comment: besides, i use anaconda.